# opengl - draw multiples elements with 2D texture

Tags: opengl, textures, glut, texture2d

I am working on a n-body code with "glut functions" display. I would like to display each body with a 2D texture from a bmp image. Currently, I can draw a single textured element with the following code :

```
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);// Clear The Screen And The Depth Buffer

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);    // pick the texture.
        glBegin(GL_QUADS); // begin drawing the textured quad.
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glEnd(); // done drawing the textured quad.
```

In the first version of my code, I draw the positions of each body with the following display function :

```
void drawPoints()
{       
        GLuint vbo;

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glVertexPointer(4, GL_DOUBLE, 4*sizeof(double), pos);   
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        if (colorVBO) {
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id_colorVBO);
            glColorPointer(4, GL_DOUBLE, 4*sizeof(double), pos);
            glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
            glEnable(GL_BLEND);
            glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        }

        glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, numBodies);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}
```

where `pos` array contains the coordinates x, y, z  of each body. I am using `glDrawArrays` function to draw all the points at the same time.

Could you tell me how to plot all the textured elements and not only one, i.e a way to use the coordinates `pos` array for indicate the positions of all the textured bodies and draw them.

Updated :

ok, I try to use glTexCoordPointer with the following display function :

```
void drawPoints()
{       
    glPushMatrix();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);// Clear The Screen And The Depth Buffer
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);    // pick the texture.
    glLoadIdentity(); // reset the view before we draw each star.
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, zoom);    // zoom into the screen. 

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    lEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(4, GL_DOUBLE, 4*sizeof(double), pos);   
    glTexCoordPointer(4, GL_DOUBLE, 4*sizeof(double), pos);

    // Assign A Color Using Bytes
    glColor4ub(30, 100, 120, 255);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  // Begin Drawing The Textured Quad
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);  glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();   // Done Drawing The Textured Quad

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, numBodies);           
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);   
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);  

    glPopMatrix();  
}
```

but only one textured element is displayed.

Anyone sees what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [glVertexPointer](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml), you should use [glTexCoordPointer](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexCoordPointer.xml). Do not forget to [enable](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml) the corresponding client state, `GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY`. There is also a complete [example](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/VBO_-_just_examples) on the official wiki, with interleaved attributes.

Note that the new (3.0+) way is to use [glVertexAttribPointer](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml) along with shaders. There's a very [descriptive page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification) on the wiki on that, as well.

Comment: "*It's much harder for simple things, though.*" There are a lot of things more complex about shader-based OpenGL; Vertex Specification is *not one of them*. With the exception of new APIs and abilities that came out afterwards (some of which apply to the old stuff to), the basic process and the functioning of glVertexAttribPointer is *no different* from that of glVertexPointer, glTexCoordPointer, and their ilk. They're actually *more complex*, because you have to remember that glColorPointer can't take non-normalized integer colors, that glVertexPointer can't take normalized integers, etc.

Comment: The only reason that page is as large as it is is because it explains *everything* about vertex specification, rather than just being a pile of example code that cargo-cult programmers can copy-and-paste into their source.

Comment: That is, of course, true - I'm quite happy with the way vertex specification turned out. How would you have me clarify my point (after all, you are compiling, linking, executing and debugging a whole new set of programs, the shaders) *and* link to the new vertex specification at the same time?

Comment: *and* clarify that I don't necessarily suggest the OP switch to the new system right now? Hmm, let me try..